# Rigify doesn't let me move my pg

Tags: armature, rigify

I have just used rigify. I follow the tutorial pretty well but i can't move it now. Can't understad why . . . the weight paint is set, control are placed but when i move one of them the mesh doesnt move. The only one that works is the cube in the center of the body.

[image]

Here the file

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just disable the "Manipulate Center Points" with the icon or by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>,</kbd> (comma).

[image: Manipulate Center Points]